# How to make windows form a background process?

Tags: c#, vb.net, process, background

so I've been seeing applications run in the background in the task manager, but when I create an application it displays in the apps section(here's what I mean):

[image: Task Manager screenshot 1]

But here is what I would like to achieve(to make it a background process):

[image: Task Manager screenshot 2]

Thanks, all help is appreciated!

Comment: You can create a Windows Service.

Comment: yes I have heard of those, but when ever I create a windows service, it doesn't install right, so that's why I had to switch to a windows form. Is there any property that can be changed or something?

Comment: you can install a windows service in the same way you install an application. Then it will be listed in your services (Windows Services)

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I do not think this is possible using normal development methods. I mean it's a form, it cant run in the background because it has a user interface. Why do you think you need to run a form in the background anyway?

Just spit balling here: Maybe you can implement just the actions you need in a Background process thread that is created in the form, then close the form. If the form runs in its own thread, perhaps you need to set the priority on the thread lower.